# how can I insert a new book in a book list inside a classroom collection using pymongo for mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of classrooms and I want to insert a new book for a specific student. I am using pymongo and mongodb.

```
{
"teacher": "teachername",
"room": 102,
"students": [
        {
        "name": "john",
        "age": 21,
        "books": [
               {
                "title": "algebra",
                "pages": 300,
                "author": "Jkrowling"
               }
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't really have time to formulate a complete answer for you. But I think that you should take a look at the positional operator `$` - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its your answer

```
db.collection.update(
    {'students.name' : 'john'},
    {$push : {'students.$.books':
       {
                    "title" : "new book",
                    "pages" : 3000,
                    "author" : "Me"
       }
     }
});
```

Comment: I would recommend using [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) as an alternative to `$push` to ensure that the same book can't be added twice.